# HDMI to VGA converter with Mac mini

Tags: hdmi, vga

I have bought a Mac mini today. My monitor is only VGA. After connecting HDMI to VGA converter my monitor is not getting any signal. How can I fix it? Please help me. I am so frustrated.

Comment: Which HDMI-VGA converter do you use?

Comment: I bought it from retailer. This is a converter but not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommended way is to use the Thunderbolt (Mini DisplayPort) to VGA converter.

http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB572Z/B/mini-displayport-to-vga-adapter?mco=MTA4NDU0NjA

The Apple HDMI does not supply signal to VGA monitors.

The Cable you have is good, but only for Digital monitors and VGA is Analog type. OK if you are sufficiently confused now, just get the Mini DisplayPort to VGA Adapter and it will work.

Comment: But this is working in PC. When I am plugging in HDMI port then My monitor works, but not with mac mini.

Comment: From PC to VGA using HDMI cable ?

Comment: Thanks. But I am becoming confused cause the same cable is working in PC

Comment: Yes, I've connected HDMI part at PC and the monitors VGA cable to VGA part. It worked.... And right now I am working in that way.

Comment: Yes, I too faced the same problem. I just understood that the HDMI out from the MacMini does not output signals to VGA. That simply means, HDMI to VGA does not work for the MacMini. As someone above told that the MiniDisplay to VGA works, do the same and it will work!

Answer (score 0):

I've gone thru the above growing pains and figured out the mini DisplayPort to VGA conversion adaptor would work for my first monitor on my Mac Mini.  However, I am installing a second monitor (I would highly recommend), and intended on using the HDMI port on my Mac Mini and a VGA to HDMI adaptor cord to connect the new monitor.

Now I learn the HDMI only works with digital monitors, which now makes sense.  Already bought the monitor, and returns are very expensive, so you'll really need the correct cables and adapters to make this work.